# Is there a way to get past the "too many values" error in Stata when using tabulate?

Tags: stata

I am trying to generate frequencies for a variable in Stata conditional on categories of another variable.

This other categorical variable has about 790,000 observations for the category I am interested in.

Stata's 12,000 rows and 1,200 rows limit for one-way and two-way tables respectively makes this impossible.

Every time I run `tab x if y==<category of interest>` I get the following error:

```
too many values
r(134);
```

I installed the `bigtab` package and though it gives me tables it cannot be used with `by` or run statistical tests.

Is there a work around for this?

It seems silly that Stata should have this arbitrary limit when SAS and even SPSS can run the exact same operation without trouble.

Answer (score 5):

To some it might seem silly, or at least puzzling, that people want tables with more than 12000 rows, as there must be a better way to display results or answer the question that is in mind.

That said, the limits of `tabulate` are hard-wired. But you just need to think of reproducing whatever you want to show. So, for one-way frequencies

```
. bysort rowvar : gen freq = _N
. by rowvar : gen tag = _n == 1 
. gsort -freq rowvar 
. list rowvar freq if tag, noobs
```

and for two-way frequencies

```
. bysort rowvar colvar : gen freq = _N
. by rowvar colvar : gen tag = _n == 1 
. gsort -freq rowvar colvar
. list rowvar freq if tag, noobs
```

A similar approach, with more bells and whistles, is coded within `groups` (SSC). An even simpler approach in many ways is to `collapse` or `contract` the dataset and then `list` it.

To flag the general strategy here:

1. Produce what you want as new variables.
2. Select just one observation from each group if there are multiple observations.
3. `list`, not `tabulate`.

UPDATE

OP asked

```
. bysort rowvar : gen freq = _N
```

OP: This generates the `freq` variable for the last count of every individual value in my `rowvar`

Me: No. The `freq` variable is the count of observations for every distinct value of `rowvar`.

```
. by rowvar : gen tag = _n == 1
```

OP: This generates the `tag` variable for the first count of every unique observation in `rowvar`.

Me: Correct, provided you say "distinct", not "unique". Unique values occur once only.

```
. gsort -freq rowvar
```

OP: This sorts `freq` and `rowvar` in descending order

Me: It sorts `freq` in descending order and `rowvar` in ascending order within blocks of constant `freq`.

```
 . list rowvar freq if tag, noobs
```

OP: What does `if` do here?

Me: That one is left as an exercise.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. (My apologies, I didn't realize hitting enter would submit the comment)

I am pretty much a novice at Stata so bear with me as I run through this code

    `bysort rowvar : gen freq = _N`

This generates the freq variable for the last count of every individual value in my rowvar

    `by rowvar : gen tag = _n == 1` 

This generates the tag variable for the first count of every unique observation in rowvar

    `gsort -freq rowvar` 

This sorts freq and rowvar in descending order

    `list rowvar freq if tag, noobs`

What does if do here?

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `bigtab`. (You have to install the package first: run `ssc install bigtab`.) For help type `h bigtab`.

Comment: The user reported problems with this command back when the question was posted.